# useQuery (tanstack/react-query) is not a function - TypeError

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

TypeError: (0 , *tanstack_react_query__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_.useQuery) is not a function.
Everything is imported correctly and I am still getting this error.

Code:

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Stripe from "stripe";

export default async function useFetchProducts() {
  async function getStripeProducts() {
    const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET ?? "", {
      apiVersion: "2023-10-16",
    });

    const res = await stripe.prices.list({
      expand: ["data.product"],
    });

    const prices = res.data;
    return prices;
  }

  return useQuery({ queryKey: ["stripeProducts"], queryFn: getStripeProducts });
}
```

I was expecting it not to throw an error that useQuery is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to pass reference for queryFn instead of calling it

```
return useQuery({ queryKey: ["stripeProducts"], queryFn: getStripeProducts });
```

Comment: I did that, no change

Comment: import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

try to import this way

Comment: that's the old way to import it. Since v5 it's @tanstack/react-query

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the package properly? (`npm i @tanstack/react-query`)

I'd also double check if there is a `@tanstack` directory in your `node_modules`

Comment: Yes, installed everything correctly and `@tanstack` is also in `node_modules`

Comment: If I hadn't installed it correctly, I would've gotten this error: `Module not found: Can't resolve '@tanstack/react-query'`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just couldn't help but to comment.
Ran into the same problem, fresh install of next14, @tanstack/react-query.
Added the first only reference on Home().

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

export default async function Home() {
  // await useFetchProducts();
  useQuery({ queryKey: ["stripeProducts"], queryFn: null });
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
```

Just by referencing useQuery itself it errors out.

Same goes for simple: useQuery();